# Android App: How can I change the icon of my Action Bar without using manifest.xml and setting minVersion to 14?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, icons

So i want to change the Icon of the ActionBar. Since the icon image depends on some input data from the user, I cannot use the manifest.xml

I also dont want to use setIcon Method because then I have to set up the minimal version to 14.

So is there any other way?

Answer (score 0):

> I also dont want to use setIcon Method because then I have to set up the minimal version to 14.

There are three possibilities for your `minSdkVersion`:

1. If your `minSdkVersion` is 10 or below, you should be using the "AppCompat" edition of the action bar, and [it has a `setIcon()` method](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/ActionBar.html#setIcon(android.graphics.drawable.Drawable)) (or use ActionBarSherlock, and it too has `setIcon()`)
2. If your `minSdkVersion` is 14 or higher, use `setIcon()` on the regular `ActionBar`
3. If your `minSdkVersion` is 11, 12, or 13, change it to be something else, as none of those values make much sense based on [the distribution of Android devices in use today](http://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

if You Dont Want to use Set Icon Method then You can use [Support Library](http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/index.html) or Action Bar Sherlock library...
There are no other option for that